# Karatsuba photo

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview

Can anyone confirm if the following link displays a photo of A. A. Karatsuba?

https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A.A.Karatsuba_in_Crimea.jpg

Comment: Is there any reason to doubt it, compared to the earlier https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AnatolyA.Karatsuba.jpg and later https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Anatolii_Karatsuba.jpg or the more adventurous https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A.A.Karatsuba_Pamir.jpg ?

Comment: The person who posted this goes by the pseudonym  ’Riemann’ and I am unable to confirm any details about this photo from them. Maybe some clarification, I would like to know the source of this photo.

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about research-level mathematics.

Comment: Worth point out that the Wikipedia articcle for Karatsuba is unusually extensive (for a mathematician): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Karatsuba

Comment: @LSpice, I agree with your comment. This question has significant historical interest.

Comment: @sam Hopkins, I am unsure what you mean by ’unusually extensive’

Comment: The page is 51 kB, compared to (for example) that on Gauss, 71kB

Comment: @J.J Green, does  this mean Gauss’ page is unusually short? I don’t think it is appropriate to form any sort of judgement on this question by the data size of Karatsubas wikipedia page.

Comment: The English Wikipedia page seems roughly to be a translation of the Russian Wikipedia page, and the Russian page has all the same photos as the English one. The image asked about here also *looks* like the others (accounting for changes in age). Is there a compelling reason to doubt the photo is genuine?

Comment: My previous comment was written when I only had access to the pages on mobile.  Now that I can compare the English and Russian Wikipedia pages side by side on a larger screen, the English page is basically a clone of the Russian one for the long parts discussing his mathematical work.  There are some differences at the very start and end of the pages related to his personal life, e.g., the end of the Russian page mentions some of his climbing achievements that do not get mentioned on the English page.

Comment: @KConrad, Thanks for this info